# Rest- How to add/include attribute in JSON data dynamically

Tags: hibernate, rest

I am working on Rest web services and producing JSON data for mobile app.I am using Jersey 1.4, web server as tomcat 7, Hibernate 3.3,MySQL5.
I am new to REST world.
I have an endpoint which simply returns a list of year based on my query.

Output:

**{"success":true,"count":2,"message":null,"data":[{"year":2012},{"year":2013}]}**

which is fine what I expected.

But I have been asked to include a description value of type string with this return json data set. Based on value of year.

If year=2012(current year) description should be "this year", for  year=2013 description ="next year", for year= 2011 description="previous year" ,for year=2010 description="2010" and so on.

**What I have to return is something like:
{"success":true,"count":2,"message":null,"data":[{"year":2012,"description":"this year"},{"year":2013,"description":"next year"}]**

My resource class

```
 @GET
@Path("/{countryCd}/upcoming")
@Produces("application/json")
public  JResponse<JsonResponse> getYearsForUpcoming(@PathParam("countryCd") 
     String  countryCode) {

     JobDao jobDao =new JobDao();   
     JsonResponse res= new JsonResponse();


   @SuppressWarnings({ })
List<Jobs> jobList=  jobDao.getYearsForUpcoming(countryCode);
   if(jobList==null){
       throw new NotFoundException("Error occured! NO data found");
   }

    int count = jobList.size();
    res.setCount(count);
    res.setData(jobList);

           return JResponse.ok(res).build();

}
```

**my query**

String sql="SELECT distinct year(s_date) as year from jobs  where country=:countryCode and year(s_date)>=year(curdate()) order by year(s_date) asc";
                Query query=session.createSQLQuery(sql).addScalar("year").setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
                query.setParameter("countryCode", countryCode);
                        upcomingRegattaList=  query.list();

**Jobs.java ( myeclipse generated entity for table jobs )**

public class Jobs implements java.io.Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer jobId;
private String status;
    private Date  SDate;
    //some more

    // getter and setters
```

}

I am clueless how to add a new attribute to my JSON data which is not in my entity. 
Any idea greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably to create one more entity to map your new object that will be something like

```
public class Data {
    private String year;
    private String description;
}
```

then load a list of this entities and add them to the response.

Comment: thank you very much , it working the way I want.  Just changed my query setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP) to setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Data.class)). Don't know wethere it is best practice but its working. Thanks again